# Azure AD B2C signUp

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I have configured an application in the Azure portal and set necessary user policies: signing and signup, password reset. I have chosen the user policy for sign-in and sign-up together. I have created a sample Nodejs app referring to the Microsoft documentation for azure b2c, its as follows,

```
const express = require("express");
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Create Express App and Routes
const app = express();


const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "******",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>",
        clientSecret: "*****"
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};


// Create msal application object
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return",
    };

    // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
    cca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
        res.redirect(response);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});

app.get('/auth/openid/return', (req, res) => {
    const tokenRequest = {
        code: req.query.code,
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return",
    };

    cca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
        console.log("\nResponse: \n:", response);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => console.log(`Msal Node Auth Code Sample app listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}!`))
```

With this code, I'm able to view the sign-in/ login page but I'm not sure how to bring the signup option here so that I can register a user with the tenant using an identity provider. How can I get a signup page/option here? Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: What doc have you followed? That looks like AAD and not AAD B2C, hence you just see a login-only page

Comment: This is the reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

Comment: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

•   You can add the sign-up page information in the node js app in azure AD B2C as shown below by using the variables used in the code: -

```
     var createError = require('http-errors');
      var express = require('express');
     var path = require('path');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
      var logger = require('morgan');
     var session = require('express-session');
      var okta = require("@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs");
       var ExpressOIDC = require("@okta/oidc-middleware").ExpressOIDC;
       var oktaClient = new okta.Client({
        orgUrl: '{yourOktaOrgUrl}',
          token: '{yourOktaToken}'
      });
       const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
       issuer: "{yourOktaOrgUrl}/oauth2/default",
           client_id: {yourClientId},
       client_secret: {yourClientSecret},
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/users/callback',
        scope: "openid profile",
        routes: {
        login: {
       path: "/users/login"
      },
   callback: {
  path: "/users/callback",
  defaultRedirect: "/dashboard"
      }
      }
      });
```

In this way, you can add the option to insert user signup option in the node js web app code.

Please find the below link for more information: -

https://github.com/instafluff/NodeJS-on-Azure-Cloud-Native-Authentication